# flutter - how to disable/make read only a specific text input field on a checkbox value change?

Tags: flutter

I have a checkbox that I would like to disable a field when it is unchecked. How would I do that? This it the current checkbox code I have so far...

```
              child: CheckboxListTile(
                title: Text("Auto Calculate Big Blind"),
                value: _autoCalcBigBlind,
                onChanged: (bool value) {
                  setState(() {
                    if (value == false) { //focus on the big blind text field
                      _bigBlindFocusNode.requestFocus();
                    } else {

                      //first check small blind is not null
                      if (_textEditControllerSmallBlind.text == null || _textEditControllerSmallBlind.text == '0'){
                        //if the field is null/0, can't double it, so focus on it
                        _smallBlindFocusNode.requestFocus();
                      }else{  //the big blind value = double the current small blind value. we know small blind field is not null
                        _textEditControllerBigBlind.text = (int.tryParse(_textEditControllerSmallBlind.text) * 2).toString();
                       **//at this point, i want a specific text input field disabled. how to do that?** 
                     }
                    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to toggle the value of the `enabled` property of `TextFormField` or `TextField`. If the `enabled` is false it would disable the `TextFormField` or `TextField`.

Create bool member such as `bool _isTextFieldEnabled = false;` in the State class of a StatefulWidget & set `_isTextFieldEnabled` to `true` when you want to disable the TextField by calling setState.

Checkout this DartPad sample I created to demonstrate this: [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/73ebd618b84c234224399d5274e8949e?null_safety=true)

Comment: since I have 5 different text input fields, does that mean i'd have to create a stateful widget for each? 

currently, these input fields are part of a list view.

Comment: No, a single stateful widget is fine.

Comment: If the ListView is not a part of a StatefulWIdget, convert it to a StatefulWidget. StatefulWidget is require for `_isTextFieldEnabled`.

Comment: Added a DartPad sample for you. Updated my answer.

Comment: Glad to help you!